# How can i set a form with multi occurence from an another table in Access

Tags: ms-access

lets assusme that in Access i have two table :

```
Parent(id,first_name,last_name)
Child(id,first_name,last_name,parent_id)
```

How, step by step, to make a form based on the Parent table, so that whil adding a parent, i can also adding his children?

Any advise or any link will be great.

Comment: Your field names here may be confusing the issue, but if you're actually trying to represent relationships between people, you really only need one table, with the fields you have in your Child table. The clue that you're storing the same entity in two different tables is that most of the fields are the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a feature called “Sub Forms”. This is designed to show this kind of parent/child relationship for example the line items on an invoice. To say me explaining how here is a link to a tutorial on the subject

http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://fisher.osu.edu/~muhanna_1/837/MSAccess/tutorials/subforms.pdf&sa=U&ei=Fkw1TfncHYuFhQf1sujdCw&ved=0CBcQFjAD&usg=AFQjCNHFGtzi9bew8Wowx9HiCQ6sccK5BA

Comment: The Northwind Sample database that ships with every version of Access may not be the best for code samples, but it does show examples of forms quite well.